# Varnish 4 Basic authentication

Tags: varnish

I have to cache multiple backend servers, I switch from Nginx to Varnish and finally discover 2 server need to run HTTP Basic Authentication. 
I try this link http://blog.tenya.me/blog/2011/12/14/varnish-http-authentication and it not work for me (they ran Varnish 3)
Is there an easy way to configure Basic Authentication in Varnish 4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the VMOD [basicauth](https://www.varnish-cache.org/vmod/basicauth)

### Install the Varnish VMOD

First you need to install it. Download the source from [the Git repo for basicauth](http://git.gnu.org.ua/cgit/vmod-basicauth.git). Extract into your homedir e.g. ~/vmod-basicauth/

You'll also need the Varnish source to build the VMOD.

In Debian/Ubuntu type

```
apt-get source varnish
```

This will copy the source to your pwd.

Then do this to install it. Note that you need to change the paths according to your setup and version of varnish

```
cd ~/vmod-basicauth
./configure VARNISHSRC=$HOME/varnish-4.0.2
make 
sudo make install
sudo make check
```

**Update**
It seems like the source have been removed from the Ubuntu and Debian package repos (most likely by accident).

Download the source directly from [Git (v4.0.2)](https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/tree/varnish-4.0.2)

**Make Varnish**

You'll have to "make" the downloaded source

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/archive/varnish-4.0.2.zip
unzip varnish-4.0.2.zip
cd Varnish-Cache-varnish-4.0.2
sudo ./autogen.sh
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make
```

Note that you don't have to install the source, so **don't "make-install"** because that might mess up your current installation.

**Build & install VMOD**

```
cd ~
./configure VARNISHSRC=$HOME/Varnish-Cache-varnish-4.0.2
make 
sudo make install
sudo make check
```

It might be that you also have to specify your VMOD install directory if it can't be autodetected. If ./configure fails try this

```
./configure VARNISHSRC=$HOME/Varnish-Cache-varnish-4.0.2 VMODDIR=/usr/lib/varnish/vmods/
```

**Some build dependencies**

I often require alot of different build dependencies so I often install these when I setup a new Varnish server.

```
sudo apt-get install git-core zlib1g-dev automake build-essential libtool libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev ncurses-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libpcre3-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-docutils python-software-properties libvarnishapi-dev
```

### Configure Varnish to use the VMOD

It uses a .htpasswd file for authentication instead of storing the password directly in the VCL.

Make sure to change "/var/www/.htpasswd" to the path of your htpasswd file.

```
#default.vcl
import basicauth;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (!basicauth.match("/var/www/.htpasswd",  req.http.Authorization)) {
        return(synth(401, "Authentication required"));
    }
}

#Prompt the user for a password
sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 401) {
        set resp.http.WWW-Authenticate = "Basic";
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Jacob, import basicauth cause me this error
import basicauth;
######-----------
Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
VCL compilation failed

Comment: Hi Billy, oh I'm sorry I missed to say that you need to install the vmod first. I'll update the answer.

Comment: hi Jacob, I stuck at getting Varnish source, I already put 'deb-src https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/ precise varnish-4.0
' in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnish-cache.list then apt-get update but it also not work 'E: Ignore unavailable version '4.0.2-1' of package 'varnish'
E: Unable to find a source package for varnish 
' when I run apt-get source varnish

Comment: it seem like very hard to configure and compile Varnish module in version 4

Comment: I tried downloading the source before doing "apt-get update" and it worked but after I get the same error as you. It seems like the Varnish team have messed up the latest packages. Check this thread: https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/3250
However try downloading it directly from Git here https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/archive/varnish-4.0.2.zip

Comment: Hi Jacob, I can not run on 12.04 becase I don't have autocon2.69. In my U14.04 it work with these command "cd vmod-basicauth
libtoolize
autoreconf
automake --add-missing
autoreconf
./configure VARNISHSRC=~/src/Varnish-Cache-varnish-4.0.2
make 
make install"

Comment: another thing after I add this  if (!basicauth.match("/var/www/.htpasswd",  req.http.Authorization)) {
        return(synth(401, "Authentication required"));
    } into one of my backend server -> The request stopped with 401 error pageinstead of asking me to input username and password. Here is my config if (req.http.host ~ "^(admin.)?example.net$") {
       set req.http.host = "admin.example.net";
       set req.backend_hint = AdExample;
        if (!basicauth.match("/home/ubuntu/.htpasswd",  req.http.Authorization)) {
          return(synth(401, "Authentication required"));
       }
    }

Comment: my backend server run node.js and it don't have any authentication method, so I need Varnish to provide basic http authentication

Comment: Good that you got it to work on 14.04 :)
I added some config for also prompting the user for a password.

Comment: hi Jacob, it's awesome! You're rock ^^

Answer (score 7):

this also works:

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (! req.http.Authorization ~ "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==") {
    return(synth(401, "Authentication required"));
  }
  unset req.http.Authorization
}

sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 401) {
    set resp.status = 401;
    set resp.http.WWW-Authenticate = "Basic";
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

src: http://blog.tenya.me/blog/2011/12/14/varnish-http-authentication/#comment-2882579903

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who follows these steps on Debian Jessie - you may come across a couple of issues when building Varnish from source.

1. That automake requires subdir-options specified in the configure.ac line 18

   ```
   AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.11 foreign color-tests parallel-tests subdir-options])
   ```
2. The Makefiles in the bin/varnishadm and bin/varnishhist require the variable $(top_srcdir) replaced with ../../ due to a bug in variable expansion in automake (see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=402727)

   ```
   varnishadm_SOURCES = \ 
           varnishadm.c \ 
           ../../lib/libvarnish/vas.c \ 
           ../../lib/libvarnish/vsa.c \ 
           ../../lib/libvarnish/vtcp.c \ 
           ../../lib/libvarnish/vss.c
   ```

Fix those and then you can follow the instructions in the answer by [jacob-rastad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3854752/jacob-rastad) above.

I have made some further notes here : http://www.blue-bag.com/blog/compiling-varnish-modules

Answer (score 2):

This is how I made basic authentication VMOD working with Varnish 4.1 in my Docker container https://github.com/blmr/varnish-basic-auth-docker

1) Install dependencies

```
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \
&& apt-get install -y git-core zlib1g-dev automake build-essential libtool libssl-dev \
libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev ncurses-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev \
libpcre3-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-docutils python-software-properties libvarnishapi-dev
```

2) Add Varnish repo

```
curl https://repo.varnish-cache.org/GPG-key.txt | apt-key add -
printf "deb https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/ trusty varnish-4.1 \ndeb-src https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/ trusty varnish-4.1" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/varnish-cache.list && apt-get update
```

3) Install Varnish 4.1

```
apt-get install -qy varnish
```

4) Get Varnish source and compile it

```
apt-get source varnish && rm *.diff.gz *.dsc *.tar.gz \
&& mv varnish* varnish-source && cd varnish-source && ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr/sbin && make
```

5) Get Varnish basic auth VMOD and compile it

```
git clone http://git.gnu.org.ua/cgit/vmod-basicauth.git && cd vmod-basicauth \
&& git clone http://git.gnu.org.ua/repo/acvmod.git && ./bootstrap \
&& ./configure VARNISHSRC=/varnish-source VMODDIR=/usr/lib/varnish/vmods/ && make && make install && make check
```

6) Update default.vcl

```
sub vcl_recv {
if (!basicauth.match("/etc/varnish/htpasswd",  req.http.Authorization)) {
            return(synth(401, "Authentication required"));
    }
}

sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 401) {
        set resp.http.WWW-Authenticate = "Basic";
  }
}
```